# DocuSign API - List Envelopes with Status Changed to 'completed' within date range

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the DocuSign API and present I'm running a query every 20 minutes to check the status of a series of Envlopes by supplying a list of Envelope IDs. It looks like I'm now passing in too many envelope IDs as I'm now getting a 404 error on my request.

I would like to refine this to just get any Envelopes where the Status has Changed to 'completed' within a date range  (e.g. the last 20 minutes). I'm polling using the the Envelopes: listStatusChanges API:

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/listStatusChanges/

I can't quite work out the syntax to make a successful request for any Envelopes that have changed to 'completed' in the last 20 minutes, e.g.:

```
GET /restapi/v2/accounts/1703061/envelopes?from_date=2019-05-08T08:30Z&to_date=2019-05-08T08:50Z&from_to_status=Completed
```

If there were 3 envelopes that were completed within that 20 minute time frame I would want those Envelopes to be returned by the request.

Comment: Are the date/times you specified in UTC? I don't see an offset.

Comment: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/polling-for-envelope-status

Answer (score 0):

Version 2.0 of our API doesn't support complex envelope searches such as the one you are trying to perform. Version 2.1 of our API that just came out have an improved envelopes search that you should look into. https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/concepts/envelopes/search you will need to change your code as the search feature has completely revamped API in version 2.1.
We're working on some code examples for the new features of API 2.1 that was just released, these will come soon.